# Не могу открыть файл для работы в Apache POI

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

Необходимо прочитать файл и распарсить его с помощью Apache POI. Файл открывается нормально, но при попытке создать WorkBook кидает исключение. Работало до обновления смартфона до Android 10, на смартфонах с более ранними версиями работает до сих пор.
Строка, в которой возникает исключение:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file)
```

Само исключение

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.nio.channels.FileChannel.close()' on a null object reference
```

Может у кого то так же возникали похожие проблемы? Буду рад помощи

Comment: На что кидает null?

Comment: на конкретно вот эту строчку

Comment: В каком месте кода эта строчка?

Comment: в отдельном классе, в котором я, собственно, занимаюсь парсингом excel таблицы

Comment: Ну это не похоже на паркинг.